# Looking for a dataset with historical SP500 (100) components

Tags: market-data

Does anyone have a dataset of a complete list of the historical (starting from the 80s 90s something like that) composition of the SP500(100) with the dates when the tickers where removed from the index? I just need the tickers and the industry.

Comment: @BobJansen, I presume this has been asked countless times before as well...it would be useful to include a link to an previous answer when closing questions like these

Comment: The link to free and cheap sources is on top. I can’t remember the specifics of all sorts of data requests and sources, sorry.

Comment: must have missed the link when commenting...my mistake.

Comment: Unfortunately non of those datasource offer the data I am looking for. However, I found what I was looking for here: https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239723/ishares-sp-100-etf